# why would a bootstrap 3 collapsible panel using glyphicon-chevron-down, show the apple gun emoji on some apple devices?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have an older c# / mvc / asp.net / bootstrap 3 application in production (intranet) for several years.  Today, I have a user complaining that instead of the down chevron (glyphicon-chevron-down) showing to collapse a panel, it is showing a green squirt-gun.  A google image search shows this as apple's emoji for gun.  Of course, I can't reproduce this on my device and this user is pretty high in my client's organization. Any ideas as to why this is happening and what I can do to prevent it?

[image: screen shot of icon]

Comment: What does the HTML specify, exactly? Can you also dig into the (bootstrap-) CSS for this icon and show that?

Comment: <i id="chevron" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>  is the exact html that's rendered.  the css is pointing to the font "Glyphicons Halflings".  I've also double checked that there are no image files in this project that contain that graphic.